# How to create css3 top border angle and opacity

Tags: css

Hello I want to produce div that have top border as triangle. So on dark part image is part visible, and at te top is not.
some think like in image any idea how to do this ?[image]

Comment: how about share some code? Div width/height?

Comment: well lets say div height 500px width 800px. Can be done in % ?

Comment: math is not my strong suit by any means, but if we're dealing with triangles I think the width/height ratio will have to stay the same - at least if we're to do this in straight CSS.
What have you tried so far?